# accessing virtual machine website(dvwa with xampp) from host machine and sniffing this traffic with mitmproxy(mitmproxy in virtual machine)

Tags: xampp, virtual-machine, mitmproxy

i have a web site which is dvwa with xampp in virtual machine. also mitmproxy is running in virtual machine. In vm i can connect dvwa website by writing http://localhost/dvwa and mitmproxy also shows the web traffic. I can also access dvwa website writing http://vm_ip_address/dvwa from my host machine. but i couldnot see dvwa web traffic(http://vm_ip_address/dvwa with host machine) in mitmproxy(which is in virtual machine).

could you please help me how can i see traffic with mitmproxy in vm?

both vm and host machine os is windows.

i tried vmware network settings as nat, bridged but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem. setting vmware as bridged network and at host machine i did proxy setting as ip adress= virtual_machine_ip and port number= mitmproxy_port_number.. when you sniff , just adjust 0.0.0.0 for mitmproxy that listen all interface.
at the host machine , write url to virtual_machine_ip:port_number/dvwa

maybe it can help someone